# space between the top of the page and my top-nav

Tags: html, css

I want to create a website that displays the time in various countries but there is a space between the top of the page and my top navigation bar. The following file has my code: https://replit.com/@FieryKing/time#index.html

Comment: Please go read [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/1427878) A proper [mre] of your issue belongs directly inside your question, not just onto an external platform.

Answer (score 1):

Add `margin: 0;` to body

```js
var currentTime = "";

function displayTime() {
  var date = new Date();
  var hour = date.getHours();
  var minute = date.getMinutes();
  var second = date.getSeconds();
  currentTime = hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second;
  document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = currentTime;
}
setInterval(displayTime, 1000);

function clearAll() {
  document.getElementById("Home").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("Time").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("Date").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("UTC").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("Contact").style.display = "none";
}

function time() {
  document.getElementById("Time").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("Home").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  margin: 0;
}

#navbar {
  background-color: aqua;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: aqua;
  position: sticky;
}

li {
  float: right;
}

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

button {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: aqua;
  padding: 20px 25px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: none;
}

li button:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: green;
}

#Time,
#Date,
#UTC,
#Contact {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>replit</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><button><a href="#Contact" onclick="home()">Contact</a></button></li>
      <li><button><a href="#UTC">UTC Time</a></button></li>
      <li><button><a href="#Date">Date</a></button></li>
      <li><button onclick="time()"><a href="#Time">Time</a></button></li>
      <li><button><a href="#Home" onclick="home()">Home</a></button></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="Home">
    <h1 id="time"></h1>
  </div>
  <div id="Time">Hi</div>
  <div id="Date">Date</div>
  <div id="UTC">UTC</div>
  <div id="Contact">Contact</div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```